# How can I Change the background color for a textview with a CSS bgcolor?

Tags: android, colors, textview, background-color

actually I'm developping an android application .The problem that I want to change the background color for a TextView using a color code that is exported from my database but it works only with CSS (bgcolor), I tried a few kinds of conversions but I n 'I could not solve this problem 
thank you for helping me
examples of color codes from my database : #66FF33 , #CC99FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your database stores the color in a String format... try this:

```
theViewYouWishToChange.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myStringWithAColor));
```

Comment: I tried this one with color codes from this site ' http://www.ordi-netfr.com/codecouleur.php ' and it works with , but when I try with color codes from my database like #66FF33 , #CC99FF (which are used with css )i've got a runtime error 
I think that i need to convert my color code to another code which can be used with java

Comment: No, strings in that format (hex) are perfectly fine to use with Color.parseColor, it must be something else, just try it with a static string, e.g. yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); this should give you a red background.

Comment: By the way, you can also use #AARRGGBB (where AA is the alpha channel)

Comment: thanks for answering me, but I should use codes values from my database which contains a html colors like #66FF33 = clear green
did you understand me ? :/

Comment: Yes. As I said above, you can use those html colors with Color.parseColor

Comment: I can't believe this android :D it makes me crazy
i tried this methode more than 10 times , it did seem to me like html color codes and the  color codes which java supported are not the same because i had runtimes error when I put it , But now it works and i didn't change anything !
Thanks  and sorry for my bad english

Comment: No problem! If this answered helped you, please mark it as correct so other people can use it too :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Color.parseColor("#rrggbb")
```

i think this is what you want right?